# chai.request() 's callback is throwing me an ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to test an express query located in app.js with mocha and chai. However the callback is throwing me an ECONNREFUSED error even though the server works perfectly when i run it.

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const app = require('../app');
const should = require("chai").should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("Login", () => {
    it("should return error when no login data", (done) => {
        chai.request(app)
            .post('/login')
            .end((error, results) => {
                if (error) throw error;
                should.exist(results);
                results.should.have.status(404);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

the full error -> 
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)

relevant code from app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require("mysql");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const saltRounds = 10;
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require("cors");
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({dest:"uploads/"});
const http = require("http");
const socketIO = require('socket.io');


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(session({
   secret:"",
   resave:true,
   saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use("/uploads",express.static("uploads"));
let con = mysql.createConnection({
//not empty in my real code 
   host:"",
   user: "",
   password: "",
   database: ""
});
let sess;

app.post("/login",function(req, res){
   con.query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = ?",[req.body.username],function (error,results) {
      if(results.length===0){
         res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/loginFailed");
         return res.status(404);
      }
      else{
         con.query("SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?",[req.body.username],
             function(error, results){
                if (error) throw error;
                console.log(results,req.body.password);
                if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, results[0].password)){
                   req.session.user = req.body.username;
                   req.session.admin = true;
                   console.log("00000");
                   sess = req.session;
                   console.log(sess.user);
                   res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/home");
                }
                else{
                   console.log("NOT OK2");
                   res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/loginFailed")
                }
             });
         }
      });
   });
server.listen(3001, function(){
});
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Do you already have something running on port 3000? Can you post your app.js if not please.

Comment: no i don't have anything else running on 3000. I just added some relevant parts of my app.js

Comment: your server seems to listen on a port 3001 instead of 3000. All over the controllers you are trying to redirect to different port, and that port is just not responds.